# Selenium does not work on ubunutu -- KeyError: 'sessionId'

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

Selenium does not work on ubunutu - KeyError: 'sessionId'.

What do I do wrong?

```
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from selenium import webdriver

display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
display.start()

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://www.python.org')

browser.close()
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/Installed/pycharm-2017.1/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1578, in <module>
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
  File "/home/user/Installed/pycharm-2017.1/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1015, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "selenium-wtf.py", line 7, in <module>
    browser = webdriver.Firefox()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 150, in __init__
    keep_alive=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 92, in __init__
    self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 180, in start_session
    self.session_id = response['sessionId']
KeyError: 'sessionId'
```

more text 
more text 
more text 
more text 
more text 
more text 
more text 
more text 
more text 
more text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updating selenium fixed it for me

```
pip install -U selenium
```